# Does Fortify support Python, Scala, and Apache Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, fortify

Does Fortify Supports Python, Scala, and Apache Spark? If it supports how to scan these codes using Fortify. 
We need to have compiler to scan C++ code using Fortify. This can be done using Microsoft visual studio.
Similarly should we need to have some plugin to scan Python, Scala, and Spark codes?

Comment: I wonder why you ask Apache Spark? Apache Spark code consists of Scala 77.4%, Java 10.0%, Python 7.7%, R 3.5%, Shell 0.5%, JavaScript 0.5%. So right question should be "does Fortify supports Python, Scala and other languages".

Answer (score 1):

Scala was not supported by all major vendors earlier in SAST domain. I just stumbled across this link (https://www.lightbend.com/blog/lightbend-and-hpe-announce-new-hpe-fortify-scala-plugin-for-static-application-security-testing-sast) which says now Microfocus (earlier HPE) supports Scala in SDLC at development phase.

As per the HPE announcement, it says "The preview version of Scala support is available for Fortify customers immediately. General availability (GA) of Scala support is scheduled to be released with release version 17.20 which will be delivered later on in 2017." Link [here](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Fortify-Blog/Fortify-Static-Code-Analyzer-Announcing-Scala-Programming/ba-p/1609078#.WbZwmNMjHUI).

Edit 1:
**Scala is supported with Fortify version 17.20 but you need to procure Scala plugin and license additionally from Lightbend.**
Also Python is a premium language and you need to procure additional license from Microfocus to use the same.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @paper1111 added context. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify Supports Python but not Scala or Spark, currently.

Based on this PDF [HPE Security Fortify Static Code Analyzer (Dec 2016)](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA5-6055ENW.pdf) in Chapter 12.

Here is a list of supported languages (second page, left side):

- ABAP/BSP
- ActionScript/MXML (Flex)
- ASP.NET, VB.NET, C# (.NET)
- C/C++
- Classic ASP (w/VBScript)
- COBOL
- ColdFusion CFML
- HTML
- Java (including Android)
- JavaScript/AJAX
- JSP
- Objective-C
- PHP
- PL/SQL
- Python
- T-SQL
- Ruby
- Swift
- Visual Basic
- VBScript
- XML

Scanning Python

To scan Python you do not need a plugin, during the translation phase you would tell SCA were the files are located along with the `-python-path` option to the import directories.

You can look at more details about scanning Python by looking at the [HPE Security Fortify Static Code Analyzer User Guide](https://www.protect724.hpe.com/docs/DOC-14804).

Note: Python is currently considered a premium language, so you need to make sure your SCA license supports scanning Python.

Comment: Thanks SBurris. If it supports python do we need to have some plug-in to compile python code..?

Comment: Thanks Seth Tisue. Yes Scala support is available in new version of Fortify i.e 17.20.

Comment: Frankly, it's a frustrating misrepresentation that Python (and other "premium" languages) are listed as supported despite requiring additional licensing. The fact that "premium language" licensing is completely omitted from all product literature, is clear evidence of this misrepresentation. If additional licensing is required for certain languages, they should say so outright. See [this discussion](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/License-Python/td-p/253565) for more details on premium licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify support python scan. Since it is not compiled, you can directly feed the code to python, it will detect the same, scan and give you the result.